# Sublime Text: Create a folder with multiple children files with one command

Tags: macros, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Is it possible to create a command that would create a folder and multiple children files with the same name and different extensions?

For example I would open the command and type in a name of "desktop-header"

the result would be the following being created

desktop-header (folder)

- desktop-header.js
- desktop-header.php
- _desktop-header.sass

I've been following [BEM](https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/) and end up needing to create all the blocks manually.

I'm not even sure what to search to see if there is an answer to this.

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can write arbitrary python code in the a command. Just select *Tools > Developer > New Plugin...* and paste the following code. This will create a folder, which contains the 3 files, relatively to the current view.

```py
import os

import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class CreateBemFilesCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        window = self.window
        view_path = window.active_view().file_name()
        if not view_path:
            sublime.error_message("Save your file first.")
            return
        base_folder_path, _ = os.path.split(view_path)

        def on_done(name):
            folder_path = os.path.join(base_folder_path, name)
            # add your file names
            file_names = [
                name + ".js",
                name + ".php",
                "_" + name + ".sass"
            ]
            file_paths = [
                os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)
                for file_name in file_names
            ]
            # create the folder
            os.makedirs(folder_path, exist_ok=True)
            # create the files
            for file_path in file_paths:
                with open(file_path, "a"):
                    pass
                # open the files in Sublime Text
                window.open_file(file_path)

        window.show_input_panel(
            "Input the folder name", "", on_done, None, None)
```

afterwards create a keybinding like this:

```js
{
    "keys": ["alt+shift+b"],
    "command": "create_bem_files",
},
```